# How to fetch Multiple news data using RSS Feed in React JS

Tags: reactjs, api, rss, feed

I already done `RSS Feed` implementation. Now I'm able to fetch 1 News using this code. I want to fetch multiple news using this code. How can I do that.

Thank in advances.

```
class FetchDataFromRSSFeed extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      recentBlogPost: {
        name: '',
        url: ''
      }
    }
  }

  FetchDataFromRssFeed() {
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.onreadystatechange = () => {
      if (request.readyState == 4 && request.status == 200) {
        var myObj = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
        for (var i = 0; i < 1; i ++) {
          this.setState({
            recentBlogPost: {
              name: myObj.items[i].title,
              url: myObj.items[i].link
            }
          });
        }
      }
    }
    request.open("GET", "https://api.rss2json.com/v1/api.json?rss_url=https%3A%2F%2Fblog.codecarrot.net%2Ffeed.xml&order_dir=desc&count=30", true);
    request.send();
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    {this.FetchDataFromRssFeed()}
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        Check out our blog: <a target="_blank" href={this.state.recentBlogPost.url}>{this.state.recentBlogPost.name}</a>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you try fetch - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I already done RSS Feed implementation. Now i'm able to fetch 1 News using this code. I want to fetch multiple news using this code.*

Instead of defining object like this,

```
recentBlogPost: {
   name: '',
   url: ''
}
```

you need to define an `array`,

```
recentBlogPost: []
```

Now instead of setting first record only,

```
var myObj = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
for (var i = 0; i < 1; i ++) {
   this.setState({
      recentBlogPost: {
         name: myObj.items[i].title,
         url: myObj.items[i].link
      }
   });
}
```

You need to set complete array,

```
var myObj = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
this.setState({
    recentBlogPost: myObj.item
});
```

And finally displaying only 1 record as,

```
<div>
   Check out our blog: <a target="_blank" href={this.state.recentBlogPost.url}>{this.state.recentBlogPost.name}</a>
</div>
```

You need to iterate over the state array,

```
{this.state.recentBlogPost.map(post=>{
    return <div key={post.title}>Check out our blog: <a target="_blank" href={post.link}>{post.title}</a></div>
})}
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the great explanation by @ravibagul91, here's the complete React component. Details on the strategy can be found in:

- [Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
- [How to Use Async/Await in React](https://www.valentinog.com/blog/await-react/)
- [Lists and Keys](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html)

```
    import React, { Component } from "react";

    export default class FetchDataFromRSSFeed extends Component {
      constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
          items: []
        };
      }

      async componentDidMount() {
        try {
          const response = await fetch(
            "https://api.rss2json.com/v1/api.json?rss_url=https%3A%2F%2Fblog.codecarrot.net%2Ffeed.xml&order_dir=desc"
          );
          const json = await response.json();
          this.setState({ items: json.items });
        } catch (error) {
          console.log(error);
        }
      }

      render() {
        console.log(this.state);
        return (
          <div>
            Check out our blog:
            {this.state.items.map(item => (
              <li key={item.guid}>
                <a target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" href={item.link}>
                  {item.title}
                </a>
              </li>
            ))}
          </div>
        );
      }
    }
```

The unstyled results look like this:

[image: Sample output]

Comment: Hmm. That code works for me. Is the array in state named `items` in your code?